# Bootstrap with composer

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, composer-php

I've downloaded bootstrapp with composer

composer.json

```
{
    "name": "afern/seocom_login",
    "require": {
        "twbs/bootstrap": "3.3.7"
    }
}
```

and I've included the autoload file on index.php

```
<?php
    include "./vendor/autoload.php";
?>
    <html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h2>Hello</h2>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Bootstrap its downloaded on vendor folder but it's not working I guess I also have to  add this line to the html code

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href=".vendor\twbs\bootstrap\bootstrap.min.css">
```

Am I right? or there is any way to work bootstrap only with

```
 include "./vendor/autoload.php"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Composer is for managing your PHP dependencies, which appears to be your backend technology of choice. However, a UI framework, such as Bootstrap, is a frontend dependency (CSS and JS).
Your proposed way of referencing the CSS in your HTML is the way to go:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
```

Same for jQuery and the Bootstrap JS:

```
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

It's probably easiest for you if you embed it from a CDN as in my examples. If you want to serve the files yourself you could use bower to manage your frontend dependencies (although I think that is discontinued).

Your composer auto load script, however, is not what you need for this.